# Is there any way to fix Terrain in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-terrain

Terrain doesn't have a texture and can't edit it's height

Terrain must look as an untextured object, but instead it looks like that:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOr07.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the default texture for a terrain.

click on the terrain and a menu should open up at the inspector, where you have a few options.

in the Project window, go to the assets folder and right click + pick create a new terrain layer.

than, you can drag this layer to the terrain and have a texture on it.

you can even drag more than one layers to have multiple textures on it.

on the height problem:
try installing the unity terrain tools package or checking if the terrain is read only.

Comment: I found out why i wasn't able to edit terrain. My brush was set to "bridge connection" or something like that by default, I set it to "raise or lower terrain" and it worked